# How to handle "Error in render: TypeError: Cannot read property 'abc' of undefined" in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Real-world data is often not as structured as we think. I remember if an angularjs template tries to access a property of undefined, it just renders an empty string. I like this default very much. When it comes to Vue, a single error will prevent the whole component from rendering.

I read about error boundary but it is unrealistic to wrap every single element that might access a property of undefined.

My question is: how to gracefully handle such errors and confidently build a component that always renders, even with bad data?

Comment: @rayhatfield I think optional chaining isn't supported yet... https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11088

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<p>{{x?x.abc:""}}</p>
```

if `x` in not defined in your data object, this will raise a warring but your app will still functioning ok.

One way to work around this warring, is to define a `getter` like for `x` in your `computed` object, something like this:

```
{ 
  data(){
    _x:null, //or it may completely missing or an empty object {}
  },
  computed:{
    x: function(){
      return this._x?this._x:{}
    }
  }
}
```

now you can use it like:

```
<p>{{x.abc}}</p>
```